# Regular Expression and Function Syntax

Tags: javascript, regex

I am doing my homework and I am stuck with a question. I am supposed to write a function that will return true if ch is 0 to 9, and false otherwise. I am not sure how to solve this. I need to use regular expression and function syntax.

```
let isDigit = (ch) => {
  for (var ch = 0; ch <= 9; ch++) {
    return true;
  }
  {
    return false;
  }
};
console.log(isDigit("7"));// expect true
console.log(isDigit("!"));// expect false
```

Comment: Try incorporating the typeof() function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use regex..

```js
let isDigit = (ch) => {
    if (ch.length > 1) {
        return false
    }
    
    return /[0-9]/.test(ch)
};
console.log(isDigit("7"));// expect true
console.log(isDigit("!"));// expect false
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let isDigit = function(ch) {     
            pattern = new RegExp("[0-9]");
            return (ch.length == 1) ? (pattern.test(ch)) : false; 
        }

console.log(isDigit("1")) ; // true
console.log(isDigit("11")) ;//false
console.log(isDigit("a")) ; //false
```

Answer (score 0):

This also works and is shorter:

```js
let isDigit = n => /^[0-9]$/.test(n);

console.log(isDigit("1"));   // expect true
console.log(isDigit("!"));   // expect false
console.log(isDigit("22"));  // expect false
```